# Undefined variable in index.php of posts in laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, undefined

**My error:**
Undefined variable: asd (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\kproject\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)

**Controller:**

```
use App\post;
public function index()
    {
          $asd = post::all();
        return view ('posts.index')->with('post','$asd');
    }
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.app')


@section('content')
    <h1> Peoples</h1>
    <hr>
   @if(count($asd)>0)
    @foreach($asd as $post)

<p> {{$post->username}}  </p>

    @endforeach

@else
<p> No Posts  </p>
   @endif



@endsection
```

I don't know why I get this error,  please help needed!

Comment: You have your $asd variable in quotes in your return view.

Comment: @Crawdingle after just removing the quotes I again got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remover upper dashes from `'$asd'`,

> change this to your controller

```
use App\post;
public function index()
{
      $asd = post::all();
    return view ('posts.index')->with('post','$asd');
}
```

to

```
use App\post;
public function index()
{
    $asd = post::all();
    return view ('posts.index')->with('post',$asd);
}
```

Assigned $asd varible to post then in view you have to iterate post varible not $asd,

> In index.blade.php,

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('content')
   <h1> Peoples</h1>
   <hr>
@if(count($asd)>0)
@foreach($asd as $post)
<p> {{$post->username}}  </p>
@endforeach
@else
 <p> No Posts  </p>
@endif
@endsection
```

Change it to,

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('content')
   <h1> Peoples</h1>
   <hr>
@if(count($post)>0)
@foreach($post as $single_post)
<p> {{$single_post->username}}  </p>
@endforeach
@else
 <p> No Posts  </p>
@endif
@endsection
```

Comment: Welcome brother,
it helps you then mark it as right answer with upvote.

Comment: Bro i have less than 15 reputations so i have been avoided to do the upvote. Once i have that status it will automatically show, as I have already did the upvoting .

Comment: thankyou bro, bro again i got a problem in form. form lai maile json ma         "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4"  rakhe ra app.php ko aliases ra providers ma pani rakhe ani auto dumo pani hane. ra composer update pani gareko tara create vanni page ma class form not found vanyo. What to do for this bro?

Comment: Brother i cant understand your language,
Please speak in english.

Comment: Sorry for that bro, please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068451/class-form-not-found-in-laravel

Answer (score 4):

You are passing `$asd` variable to view ... but with a different name. Name in view would be `$post`.

`->with('post', $asd)` ... pass $asd variable to view and assign it to $post

change index.blade.php to something like:

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
<h1> Peoples</h1>
<hr>
@if(count($post)>0)
    @foreach($post as $p)

    <p> {{$p->username}}  </p>

@endforeach

@else
    <p> No Posts  </p>
@endif
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be passing data to Laravel view by 2 type of method.

**1 Using `->with()` method.**

Your Controller method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $post_data = post::all();
        return view('posts.index')->with('post',$post_data);
    }  

}
```

**OR**

**2 You can pass an array the second argument of `view()` method.**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $post_data= post::all();
        $post_data = ['post' => $post_data]
        return view('posts.index')->with('post',$post_data);
    }  

}
```

You can access it in `Index.blade.php` by following

```
{{$post}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am new to laravel I get a bit confused at times and yet I m not understanding the whole process.

Firstly i removed the quotes from $asd but i have passed the same variable to view.

As mentioned above by @Bostjan, I would like to know the process, can anyone clarify this to me

> You are passing $asd variable to view ... but with a different name.
>   Name in view would be

```
 $post->with('post', $asd)
```

> ... pass $asd variable to view and assign it to $post

Comment: Read "Passing data to views" in views offical documentation:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views

Answer (score 0):

I identified this problem.
You send the **posts** variable in the **index** function.

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
```

But most likely you get this error when you want to **create a new post**, so here the **store function** is executed and the **index function** is not executed in the controller, because the store function is responsible for storing form information. Then you edit this function as follows.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = new Post();
    $post->title = $request->input("title");
    $post->description = $request->input("description");
    $post->save();


    $posts = Post::all(); //Send posts in compact
    return view("posts.index", compact($posts));
}
```

Excuse me for the typing problem, I am a Persian speaker ❤