# Class form not found in laravel

Tags: laravel

Error :

```
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Class 'Form' not found in kproject.dev/posts/create
```

I have added these to aliases:

```
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

And added this to providers:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

This is create.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>Create</h1>
    <hr>
    {!!Form::open(['action'=>'postscontroller@store','method'=>'POST']) !!}


    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

Comment: Do you update your composer after added?

Comment: Run composer dump-autoload

Comment: http://laraveldaily.com/class-form-not-found-in-laravel-5/

Comment: follow this and add a html facade to your composer and update the composr

Comment: i ran the composer dump-autoload and did check but it still shows the error.

Comment: i added "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0",  to composer.json's include and did composer update still not working.

Answer (score 0):

i found the way to do this i just added this command `composer require laravelcollective/html`

Just use this command in terminal and it will work.You just do not need to alter `json` file.